# Place banners side by side using HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

How to put banners side by side using HTML/CSS? Ideally with different sizes as shown below?

[image]

Comment: Use grid of 12 columns, small one takes 4 columns, big one takes 8. You can use Bootstrap grid. Also you can make table.

Comment: Give fixed widths and `display: inline-block` ?

Comment: I agree with @Justinas try to use Bootstrap grid.

Comment: If you are familiar with `twitter-bootstrap` then use its Grid system otherwise using `inline-block` will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Either use some grid system, or the bare CSS float property, pseudo example shown below:

```css
.banner1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
.banner2 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
.banner3 {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner1">banner</div>
<div class="banner1">banner</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="banner2">banner</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="banner3">banner</div>
<div class="banner3">banner</div>
<div class="banner3">banner</div>
<div class="banner3">banner</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to display the banners `inline-block`, and assign them the required width.

```css
.banner {
    display: inline-block;
}

.banner-sm {
  width: 32%;
}

.banner-lg {
  width: 65%;
}

.banner {
    height: 100px;
    background: #DDD;
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="banner banner-lg"> </div>
   <div class="banner banner-sm"> </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="banner banner-sm"> </div>
   <div class="banner banner-sm"> </div>
   <div class="banner banner-sm"> </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="banner banner-sm"> </div>
   <div class="banner banner-lg"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with `twitter-bootstrap` then use its Grid system otherwise using `inline-block` will help you.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<section style="width:650px">
  <div style="width:415px;"></div>
  <div style="width:200px;"></div>
  <div style="width:200px;"></div>
  <div style="width:200px;"></div>
  <div style="width:200px;"></div>
  <div style="width:200px;"></div>
  <div style="width:415px;"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to get grid system and other useful layout functionality:

```css
.row div {
  height: 30px;
  background: #aaa;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-xs-8'></div>
  <div class='col-xs-4'></div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-xs-4'></div>
  <div class='col-xs-4'></div>
  <div class='col-xs-4'></div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-xs-4'></div>
  <div class='col-xs-8'></div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-xs-4'></div>
  <div class='col-xs-8'></div>
  <div class='col-xs-8'></div>
  <div class='col-xs-4'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **CSS3 flex-box** concept

```css
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    flex-direction:column;
}

.flex-item {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
.sub{
 height:100%;
    background:white;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.one{
width:75%;
border:1px solid green;
}
.two{
 width:25%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.subb{
width:33%;
background:white;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
   <div class="sub one">sub 1 </div>
    <div class="sub two">sub 2 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
   <div class="subb s3">sub 3 </div>
    <div class="subb s4">sub 4 </div>
    <div class="subb s5">sub 5 </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**You can use Bootstrap to do this.**

> Bootstarp is a Powerful css framework which enables web developer's
>   to do stuff like these(dividing screens etc).

Bootstrap is very easy to learn and implement.

You can start Learning Bootstrap [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey, this is not a link only answer. And I'd suggest you stop down voting everybody with your copy-paste comment. Thank you

Comment: Bootstrap isn't `Jquery Library` Its an HTML, CSS, and JS Framework.